# how to generate multiple ip's in the same subnet for a particular machine in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ip-address

I want to generate multiple ip's for a particular virtual machine in ubuntu all in the same subnet. How can this be done? I need multiple ip's as I want to perform load testing on a particular server using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each IP is linked to a virtual/physical interface, so you need a virtual machine with X network interfaces. You should add these in your virtualization software. Afterwards ensure that your VM's are accessible through your host (e.g. setting the interface in 'bridged mode' Warning this is not considered a good security practice).

You could also launch multiple VM's with one interface each, but this would generate much more overhead and doesn't seem optimal.

EDIT: I would not use multiple VM's to do load testing, there are tools for that ( e.g. https://locust.io/ ) or build a custom one.

Comment: How/Where should i specify the the IP range of addresses which I want?

Comment: Oh, I am trying to use just one VM to simulate multiple users

Comment: Why would you need differents ip's for load testing  ?

Comment: To simulate multiple users at the same time? Is there a better way to do this rather than using multiple ip's?

Comment: Would using locust.io be a better option?

Comment: i've edited my post, yes, definitly. Even using a custom script would be a better option, if you can have multiple user sessions on the same ip why would you need so many ip's ? :)

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help!:) I will try using a custom script for multiple user sessions instead of multiple ip's

Comment: np, depending on your needs you should maybe look for an alreay made tool and tweak it to your needs, this will save you a lot of time not reinventing the wheel. PS:feel free to accept the answer if it works out for you

Comment: Other than locust, are there any other tools which you would suggest(which use python)?

Comment: I am finding it hard to get the results from locust in a format which I can manipulate to get the throughput. I just need to find to finally display the throughput in terms of mbps and latency.

Comment: have a look at this : https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/ it's maybe more suited to your needs.